# Is it possible to toggle fullscreen without recreating the window?

Tags: opengl, window, cross-platform

Do the three major operating systems Linux, Windows and Mac support toggling between fullscreen and windowed mode without recreating the window? Recreating is problematic since it implies to recreate the OpenGL context as well, or at least some OpenGL objects.

What API functions are available on those platforms for performing the task?

Comment: I use `SDL2` to do this. `SDL1` was a bit of a nightmare getting full screen working. Have no experience with mac though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows: Yes

X11/GLX: Yes

MacOS-X: It's complicated.

---

First the easy stuff: In Windows and X11 there are no such things as *special fullscreen mode* OpenGL windows. They're all just regular toplevel windows and you can add or remove the window decorations (title bar, border) anytime you like. If you remove the window decorations and set the window size to maximized you essentially get a fullscreen OpenGL window; in fact the graphics drivers are smart enough to detect this situation and switch to a fast track then.

---

Now MacOS X. In MacOS X clear distinction is made between [Windowed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_drawing/opengl_drawing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH404-SW8) and [Fullscreen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH210-SW6) (which IMHO is quite annoying).

The good news is, that you can get access to the underlying context object which allows to implement some resource sharing so that you don't have to recreate the data containing OpenGL objects.

**Big Fat Disclaimer**: I never ventured as deep into MacOS X as I did with other OSs so my practical experience with this certain topic on MacOS X is only theoretical.

Comment: On Windows, all my three monitors are black for a second when switching a window on one screen into fullscreen mode. So it seems to me that there is a state change, too. What do you think?

Comment: @danijar I'd be inclined to agree, though I know very little about the details. There's huge functionality (and sometimes performance) differences on windows between full screen 3D apps and windowed mode. I commonly run games in window mode and remove their decoration manually so things like alt-tab and other 3D apps or vlc don't break.

Comment: @danijar: That mode change you observing is completely independent from the toggle to fullscreen. What happens is, that (in Windows) the program calls the function `SetDisplaySettings` to switch the display to the desired resolution and frequency *and thereafter* creates a window filling the screen. In X11/GLX there's similar functionality through the XRandR extension with the Xlib based XRR function `XRRSetScreenConfigAndRate`.

Comment: @danijar: The whole mode switching old games do is an anachronism though. It was done to limit the resolution the GPU had to render, i.e. to trade performance for image quality. These days the preferred method of doing so is by rendering into a framebuffer object (FBO) of the desired resolution and then as a postprocessing step draw this to a native sized fullscreen window. The advantage of doing it this way is, that it doesn't stomp on the user's personal system configuration. For example in older Windows versions changing the display mode usually messed up the Desktop Icon arrangement.